# Let $f\colon\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ be a continuous surjection. Prove there exists a closed interval $I$ such that $f(I)= [0,1]$.

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f\colon\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ be a continuous surjection. Prove there exists a closed interval $I$ such that $f(I)= [0,1]$.

I basically just need help getting this proof started. I think the surjection part is throwing me off. Any kind of advice word be great! Thanks!

Comment: Please note there was a mistake in my answer. Should have started with $f(c)=0$, $f(d)=1$ with say $c\lt d$. Then let $b$ be the inf over $c\lt x\le d$ such that $f(x)=1$. And then (the missed step) should have taken $a$ as the sup over $c\le x\lt b$ such that $f(x)=0$.

Comment: Principles of Mathematical Analysis by Walter Rudin.

Answer (score 2):

Let $c$ be a point for which $f(c)=0$.  Let $b$ be the closest point to $c$ for which $f(b)=1$. (If there's a tie, take the one with $b\gt c$.)  Then let $a$ be the closest point to $b$ in the interval with endpoints $b$ and $c$ for which $f(a)=0$.  The existence of these "closest points" is guaranteed by the fact that $f$ is continuous and surjective.  The interval with endpoints $a$ and $b$ is what you want.

(Note:  I initially took $a$ to be the closest point to $b$ with $f(a)=0$ without requiring it to be between $b$ and $c$, but as D. Thomine pointed out, that was a mistake.)

Comment: There is a missing argument. You need to take $a$ in the interval with end points $b$ and $c$.

Comment: @D.Thomine, you're absolutely right!  Thank you, I'll fix it.